# How can you port AS3's mx.validators.EmailValidator.validate() to VB.Net? (The criteria for validatation is sufficient.)

Tags: vb.net, actionscript-3, apache-flex, validation, email

We have a system whose front-ends are primarily in AS3 and VB.Net.  There's a certain place in the AS3 side that is validating e-mail addresses through `mx.validators.EmailValidator.validate()`, and we're trying to port this sort of validation over to a spot in the VB.Net side that shares a lot of the same functionality.

If reasonably possible, this needs to be done with exactly the same criteria that `EmailVaidator` is using in its `validate()` function.  In all honesty I know that this is pretty close to simply a question of whether something is or is not a valid e-mail address, but I don't know that there aren't rare exceptions in which `validate()` may be showing occasional leniency or something.

How could you port the exact same functionality over to VB.Net?  If I just knew the criteria `EmailValidator` is using, I could write the code myself.  The problem is that I haven't seen a specification for this so far, despite Googling and looking at documentation.  What are the criteria for this, **OR** what might might be some library or something that I could use to achieve this?  If this just isn't going to work, and if the VB.Net side needs to be coded from a VB.Net library or something, that's also a valid answer (please justify though).  Thanks!

Comment: The Flex Framework is open source.  why can't you just open up the source code for mx.validators.EmailValidator and convert it to VB.Net?  In Flash Builder [on Windows]; you can control click on the class name to bring up the source code.  Or here is the source from the Apache Flex SDK: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-sdk/repo?p=flex-sdk.git;a=blob;f=frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/validators/EmailValidator.as;h=f928371b08ecddb9e2ad3dfa49082204237edf4c;hb=HEAD

Comment: Thanks.  Go ahead and turn this into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Done! I wasn't sure if that appropriately answered your question or not which is why I started w/ a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flex Framework is open source.  So, you should be able to get the [source code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-sdk/repo?p=flex-sdk.git;a=blob;f=frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/validators/EmailValidator.as;h=f928371b08ecddb9e2ad3dfa49082204237edf4c;hb=HEAD) for the [EmailValidator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/EmailValidator.html) class from the Apache Flex project and convert it to VB.Net or any technology you prefer.

In Flash Builder [on Windows]; you can easily bring up the source from a Flex Framework class by control clicking on the class name, such as when it is imported; or when a variable is created of that type, or when the class is defined in MXML.  You can also use the "open type" option from the Navigate menu and select the class name from the list.

I assume both of the above approaches would be doable on a Mac.